# Fluent/Fabric - Is it possible to clear the input of the NormalPeoplePicker programmatically?

Tags: office-ui-fabric

Is it possible to clear the input text (e.g. "qweqweqweqwe" in the example below) of the (Fluent/Fabric) NormalPeoplePicker programmatically?

I have tried accessing the input element (via the onBlur event) and attempted to change it's **value** and **innerHtml** but that doesn't work. Also, that doesn't seem to be a good way of doing it.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/peoplepicker

[image]

Comment: Take a look at this example `line 104` https://codepen.io/savkelita/pen/bGwwNmP Seems like they keep input value inside state and its not possible to change it directly. I'm using `onBlur` event and `updateValue` method. This is a hack, but maybe a good point to start. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/pickers#implementation

Comment: @MarkoSavic Thanks. Completely agree with your comment but it does work and will suffice for the moment. If you turn your comment into answer I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NormalPeoplePicker Component` keep input value inside `state` and its not possible to change it directly:

```
const picker = React.useRef(null)

...

<NormalPeoplePicker
  ...
  onBlur={() => {
    if(picker.current) {
      picker.current.input.current.value = ""; // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property value of #<Autofill> which has only a getter
    }
  }}
/>
```

From [Official Documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/pickers#implementation) inside implementation section there is useful method `updateValue` which allows to change the input value.

```
const picker = React.useRef(null)
...

<NormalPeoplePicker
  ...
  onBlur={() => {
    if(picker.current) {
      picker.current.input.current._updateValue("");
    }
  }}
/>
```

[Codepen working example](https://codepen.io/savkelita/pen/bGwwNmP) `ln: 104`.

**Note:**

*This is a temporary solution, test every use case before production.*

Comment: As Marko says, this is undefined behaviour. It works but a React/Fluent property would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

```
let orgSelected: ITag[] = [];
orgSelected.push({key:0 name:''});
const [selectedOrg,setselectedOrg] = useState(orgSelected);
On TagPicker Property just assign the statevalue like this.
selectedItems={selectedOrg}

This way the tagpicker property will always be selected with an empty item.
```